# AFNetworking Array returns JSON inside of block but not outside of block

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, afnetworking

I've created a custom method that returns JSON data using the AFNetworking API.

I'm trying to store data pulled from my web service in an Array as JSON. NSLog(@"%@", json); inside the block prints the JSON data to console. Outside the block NSLog(@"%@", json); return null. Why is this and how can it be fixed?

What I'm trying to do is to get the method to return the JSON data (NSArray)

```
#import "WebService.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@implementation WebService

- (NSArray *)postRequest:(NSDictionary *)postParameters {

//MBProgressHUD *progressHUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
//progressHUD.labelText = @"Loading";

__block NSArray *json;

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:@"http://192.168.0.100/app.php" parameters:postParameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSString *responseString = [operation responseString];

     NSError *error;

     json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

     NSLog(@"%@", json); // RETURNS JSON

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Unavailable"
                                                     message:@"Unable to contact server. Please try again later."
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show];

     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

 }];

     NSLog(@"%@", json); // RETURNS NULL

     return json;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

The `POST` method is asynchronous.  Meaning that that block goes to a separate thread and waits to execute.  While that is going to the background the rest of your code continues on as though nothing happened.  So it gets immediately to the `NSLog` statement(probably before even starting you `POST` request).

If you want the `json` object outside of your block you are going to have to dispatch from inside the block to a method of your choosing and continue your operations there.

```
[manager POST:@"http://192.168.0.100/app.php" parameters:postParameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSString *responseString = [operation responseString];

     NSError *error;

     json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

     NSLog(@"%@", json); // RETURNS JSON
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [self doSomethingWithJson:json];
     });

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Unavailable"
                                                     message:@"Unable to contact server. Please try again later."
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show];

     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

 }];
```

Comment: I can see how that would work. What I'm trying to do is to get the method to return the JSON data (NSArray).

Comment: @user2920762 Understood. But what we're all trying to tell you is that you should not do that. You never want the main queue to wait for a network request (never block the main queue). And the only way to make `postRequest` to return the JSON object is to make it block the main queue and behave synchronously, which is inadvisable. Use asynchronous patterns like all of these various answers all illustrate.

Comment: A small note: The dispatch to the main queue is unnecessary because AFNetworking guarantees that its completion ocks are called on the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

Because `POST` runs asynchronously, it's not possible to return the results. But you can employ the same completion block pattern that AFNetworking does:

```
- (void) postRequest:(NSDictionary *)postParameters success:(void (^)(id jsonObject))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:@"http://192.168.0.100/app.php" parameters:postParameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         if (success)
             success(responseObject);
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Unavailable"
                                                         message:@"Unable to contact server. Please try again later."
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];

         if (failure)
             failure(error);        
     }];
}
```

And you call that as:

```
[self postRequest:postParameters success:^(id jsonObject) {
    NSLog(@"json = %@", jsonObject);
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
}];
```

Note, I've simplified your code significantly, because you don't have to do the JSON parsing, because AFNetworking already does that for you (because the default `responseSerializer` is `AFJSONResponseSerializer`). So as you can see, your above method doesn't do much more than the standard AFNetworking `POST` method which shows a `UIAlertView` if there was an error.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to wat @Putz1103 says, you could use callback methods, this is a technique also used in JavaScript.

Example:

```
[manager POST:@"http://192.168.0.100/app.php" parameters:postParameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSString *responseString = [operation responseString];

     NSError *error;

     json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

     NSLog(@"%@", json); // RETURNS JSON
     [self dataRetrievedWithData:json];

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Unavailable"
                                                     message:@"Unable to contact server. Please try again later."
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show];

     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

 }];
```

Then you would have a method like:

```
- (void)dataRetrievedWithData:(id)data
{
  NSLog(@"Here's the data.. do what you want to do with the data here. %@", data);
}
```

In that last method you can add logic to execute when the request is completed successfully. Returning from the block is not really feasible since the block is executed on a separate thread.

The operation is asynchronous which means you can simply print out the response after it arrives. Asynchronous means it runs in a separate thread so you have to wait for the response prior to being able to do anything with the response.